# Need help for algorithm to calculate position from current position like this (geometry 2D)

Tags: android, opengl-es, geometry

See image below:

[illustration http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/5286/pic1we.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/5286/pic1we.png)

Assume it's on android device screen. Dot #1 is the current position. I want to get the (x,y) position of Dot #2 following the linear blue line (let's say the range between dot #2 and dot #1 is 50dp). The black box is the source point of the blue line.

What is the term for this? Translation?

Is there anyone know the algorithm?

I developed android application using AndEngine, if you know there is built-in function for that, please let me know. Same too for android openGL ES library.

Note: I'm not looking for a way to move object using MoveModifier.

Thx in advance.

Comment: What is the black box? How is the blue line represented? Also, you don't have enough constraints here -- there's an infinite number of points that lie on the blue line. What makes point 2 special/different from other points on the line?

Comment: Hi, I already updated my question. In simple, black box is the source point of the blue line. The blue line is a linear line. Assume the dot #2 position is -50dp from the dot #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authman's answer is good, but doesn't include how to get a specific distance away. If you're looking for p2 along the line, IMO it's easier to think about this in vectors. First you find the vector along the blue line, which is similar to the process that Authman describes above. If the black box has position `v0 = (x0, y0)` and the first dot has position `v1 = (x1, y1)`, then your "direction vector" is going to be `v1 - v0 = (x1 - x0, y1 - y0)`. This is a vector that points along the blue line. Once you have that, you normalize it so that the length is 1, and then multiply it by your desired distance, in your case 50. If you want to do it component-wise, here's some quick pseudocode:

```
find_v2(x0, y0, x1, y1):
  direction_x = x1 - x0
  direction_y = y1 - y0

  norm = sqrt(direction_x^2 + direction_y^2)
  direction_x *= 50 / norm
  direction_y *= 50 / norm

  x2 = x1 + direction_x
  y2 = y1 + direction_y
```

Hope that helps! I'm not sure how comfortable you are with vector math, but if you're doing graphics stuff, it can be really, really useful for problems like this; I'd recommend checking out some of the [Khan Academy Linear Algebra courses](http://www.khanacademy.org/#linear-algebra).

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. Actually, the dot #2 position that I want is outside-of-screen position, I can do it by looping your above code by changing the constant 50 to 1. But the problem is I don't know how to detect if the (x2,y2) is already out screen. What I can think is: A. If x1 is at left of x0, the constraint is: (x2 < 0) or (y2 < 0). B. If x1 is at right of x0, the constraint is: (x2 > SCREENWIDTH) or (y2 < 0). C. If x1 is same width x0, the constraint is just: (y2 < 0). Is that correct? What do you think?

Comment: Hi, so the black box position (x0, y0) is mandatory? Is it possible to find the dot #2 (x2,y2) position without knowing the (x0,y0) position?

Comment: Having two positions on the line is necessary, because a line must have two points to be uniquely defined. There are many lines that pass through (x1, y1) -- you need another point to define the line uniquely. The off-screen bit is trickier -- I'll give it a think.

Comment: For offscreen issue, I found a way without using loop. I just use simple calculation by considering current (x,y) pos and also comparing who's closer between current x & y

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is [extrapolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation).

If the black dot is dot '0', then you first calculate your line equation's slope:

```
m = ( (d0.y-d1.y) / (d0.x-d1.x) )
```

Then you can extrapolate along that line, either positively (away from point 0) or negatively (towards it, until you get to it, and then eventually again away from in continuing in the line of motion).

```
dot2.x = d0.x + m*percentage
dot2.y = d0.y + m*percentage
```

Where `percentage` is how close you are to dot 1. Thus 1 (eg 100%) would put you on dot 1 exactly. percentage=0 would put you on dot 0 exactly. >1, would put you closer to dot 2. <1 would move you past dot 0, etc.

--

Slight correction there:

```
dot2.y = d0.x + m*percentage
dot2.x = (dot2.y - dot0.y) / m
```

The slope as i set it up is only useful for calculating the y coordinate of dot2. Since you already have the equation of the line, you can solve for dot2's x-coord directly using it.

Comment: Hi, I already updated my question. How if the range between dot #2 and dot #1 is 50 dp?